# c# windows phone 8.1 creating udp socket

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-phone-8, udp

I am quite new with c# and app developing. How do I establish connection and send packets via UDP. I have tried to follow 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202864(v=vs.105).aspx
It doesn't work as it is ment for wp8

Comment: Do you really need create and send data over a UDP socket or this is just a "Let me try do it"/"Homework" kind of problem?

Comment: Currently what I am trying to do is to send sensor values through UDP stream onto server - DB and than work around with those values in LabView

Answer (score 1):

My here is not a real answer, but a workaround.
Instead of worrying about sending values via UDP socket, I'd suggest you to use a buffer/queue and implement a REST API on the server side, sending the data via HTTP requests, which is more reliable and easier to maintain...
You, of course, would send them in a async fashion, and you would still be able to juggle them up anyway you want server side...

Comment: Thanks. I have solved the problem by sending http request and than just store them into the DB via php script